# transpecで実行後is deprecated. Use `respond_to_missing?` or `respond_to?` on your object instead.が出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

rspec2.99でテスト全部ok後transpecを実行しました。以下ワーニングが出るようになりました。

```
Matching with be_hoge_fixed on an object that doesn't respond to `hoge_fixed?` is deprecated. Use `respond_to_missing?` or `respond_to?` on your object instead. Called from /hoge/poge/workspace/transpec4.0/spec/controllers/hogehoge/hoges_controller_spec.rb:207:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'.
```

テストコードは以下の感じです。

```
context "かつ、情報が存在しない場合、" do
  before(:each) do
    Pogepoge.stub_chain(:hoge_at, :exists?){false}
  end
  it "falseを返す" do
    expect(controller).not_to be_hoge_fixed
  end
end
```

プロダクトコードは以下のようです。

```
def hoge_fixed?
  return false unless poge_selected?
  unless HOGE.exists?
    return false
  end
  true
end


def poge_selected?
  if params[:poge_month].blank?
    return false
  end
  true
end
```

ワーニング解消方法を知りたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

警告が出る原因を端的に言うと、おそらく`hoge_fixed?`がprivateメソッドになっているせいです。

警告文は以下のコードで出力されています。

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/2-99-maintenance/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/be.rb

```
    # ...

        @result = actual.__send__(predicate, *@args, &@block)
        check_respond_to(predicate)

    # ...

    def check_respond_to(method)
      RSpec.deprecate(
        "Matching with #{@prefix}#{@expected} on an object that doesn't respond to `#{method}`",
        :replacement => "`respond_to_missing?` or `respond_to?` on your object"
      ) unless actual.respond_to?(method)
    end
```

`__send__`とで呼び出すと値が返るが、`respond_to?`をチェックするとfalseが返る、というのは、Rubyの言語仕様から想像するに、privateメソッドの可能性が高いと思います。

解決策はいくつか考えられます。

1. 間接的に`hoge_fixed?`をテストする（「`hoge_fixed?`がfalseになるはずなので、`foo_path`にリダイレクトすればOK」、みたいなテストを書く）
2. `hoge_fixed?` をpublicメソッドにする
3. `expect(controller.send(:hoge_fixed?)).to be_truthy` のように、privateメソッドを直接呼び出す。

個人的なオススメは1です。
ネットを見ていると、3のアプローチを紹介している記事もよく見かけます。
しかし、privateメソッドはprivateメソッドのままにしておき、あくまで「外からは呼び出せないこと」を前提としたテストコードにすべき、というのが僕の考え方です。

Comment: expect(controller.send(:hoge_fixed?)).to be_truthyで動くようになりました。１の方法でもテストを書き換えられるか見てみます。